# How do I deselect all cells in an NSBrowser

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsbrowser

How do I deselect/unselect any selected cells in an NSBrowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of [here](http://homepage2.nifty.com/hoshi-takanori/cocoa-browser/prog-tips.html#browser-unselect):

```
[browser loadColumnZero];
```

Note that browser selection changed sent action does not get sent in this case, so you may have to trigger that method manually if you're using that action in Interface Builder.